# Plot geocode: ggmap error

Tags: r, maps, ggmap

I want to visualize a dataframe with R and the ggmap package.

df:

```
| lon       | lat       |
|-----------|-----------|
| 6.585863  | 51.09021  |
| 8.682.127 | 50.11092  |
| 7.460.367 | 5.152.755 |
```

I created a map with

```
mapImageData <- get_googlemap(
+   "Germany", 
+   zoom=15
+ )
```

And then wanted to add the geocodes:

```
ggmap(mapImageData) +
+     geom_point(aes(x=lon, y=lat), data=df, colour="red", size=5)
```

But I get the error:
**Error: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't know if it is related to your problem, but you need to check your lon and lat (two "." in three of them).

Comment: @Henrik @user2874571 probably something went wrong with converting the data. There should be only 1 decimal point. Furthermore the decimal point for the last `lat` value probably needs to go 1 place to the right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have three problems:

1. More than one deicmal point in some values & decimal points probably not at the right place (see also my comment)
2. The map is centered on the wrong spot
3. The zoom level is to high

Let's fix this:

```
# Get the right data
ger <- read.table(text="lon lat
6.585863 51.09021
8.682127 50.11092
7.460367 51.52755", header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)

# Finding a good centerpoint
mean(ger$lon) # outcome: 7.576119
mean(ger$lat) # outcome: 50.90956

# Get the map; you might have to try several zoomlevels te get the right one
library(ggmap)
mapImageData <- get_googlemap(center = c(lon = 7.576119, lat = 50.90956), zoom=8)

# Plot the points on the map
ggmap(mapImageData) +
  geom_point(data=ger, aes(x=lon, y=lat), colour="red", size=6, alpha=.6)
```

The resulting map:

[image]